# How to use a DN containing commas as the attribute value in an LDAP search filter?

Tags: syntax, ldap, ldap-query

Was attempting to search our directory based on an attribute whose value is a DN. However, our user RDNs are of the form `CN=Surname, GivenName`, which requires that the comma be quoted in the full DN. But given an attribute like `manager` whose value is the DN of another user, I was unable to search for all users having specific manager. I tried `(manager=CN=Surname\, GivenName,CN=users,DC=mydomain,DC=com)`, but got a syntax error "Bad search filter". I tried various options for quoting the DN, but all either gave me a syntax error or failed to match any objects. What am I doing wrong?

(Note that if I were looking for user objects directly, I could search for simply `(CN=Surname, GivenName)`, with no quoting required, but I was searching for users having a specific manager. The comma-containing attribute value only becomes a problem when part of a Distinguished Name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that quoting the comma in the Common Name is not for the benefit of the filter parser, but for the benefit of the DN parser; the attribute value passed to that by the filter has to literally contain the backslash character. Unfortunately, the backslash is also (differently) special in LDAP filters, thus the syntax errors.

The solution is simple, but it isn't as obvious as doubling the backslash; backslash in LDAP filters works like `%` in URIs, so you have to use a literal backslash followed by the 2-digit hexadecimal code point for a backslash:

```
(manager=CN=Surname\5c, Givenname,OU=org,DC=mydomain,DC=com)
```

It turns out there's an example of this specific use case at the very bottom of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/gdxpo/index.html#6ng8i269q.